# embe a minimize fitting in a minimize function, the parameter don't change

Tags: python-3.x, lmfit

I try to fitting a 3d-matrix with multi-exponential function, as

S(w1,w2,T) = sum( A_i(w1,w2)*exp(-T/tau_i) )

To reducing fitting time, I divided it to two steps.

Define a objective function only with life time (tau_i) as the parameters, while embed a minimize fitting within the objective function as shown in the code.

The problem is that "when I minimize the objective function, the parameters don't changing?"

```
#data, is 3d matrix, data[k,i,j]
ltn = 4

#build the amplifer fitting model        
def fit_2ddas_amp(params, dat, dec):
    model_amp = np.zeros(len(waitT),np.float)
    for k in range(ltn):
        model_amp = model_amp + params['amp_%i'%(k)] * np.exp(-waitT/dec[k])
    resid_amp = dat - model_amp
    return resid_amp 

#build the decay time fitting model
def fit_2ddas_decay(par_decay):
    decay_fit = np.zeros(ltn,np.float)
    for i in range(ltn):
        decay_fit[i] = par_decay['decay_%i'%(i)]
        print('Decay', str(i+1), ':', '%.6f'%(decay_fit[i]), 'ps' )
    resid = np.zeros_like(data)
    #do the amplifier fitting
    for i in range(len(wt)):
        for j in range(len(wtau)):
            #create initial value of amplifier
            par_amp = Parameters()
            for k in range(ltn):
                par_amp.add('amp_%i'%(k), value = 2 )
            #do the amplifer fit
            minner_amp = Minimizer(fit_2ddas_amp, par_amp, fcn_args=(data[:,i,j], decay_fit), nan_policy='propagate')
            result_amp = minner_amp.minimize(method='least_squares')  
            resid[:,i,j] = result_amp.residual
    return resid.flatten()


#create parameters of decay
par_2ddas_decay = Parameters()
for i in range(ltn):
     par_2ddas_decay.add('decay_%i'%(i), value = 2, min = 0.0)

#do the decay time fit
minner_decay = Minimizer(fit_2ddas_decay, par_2ddas_decay, nan_policy='propagate')
result_decay = minner_decay.minimize() 

the decay time always the same.
Decay 1 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 2 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 3 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 4 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 1 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 2 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 3 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 4 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 1 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 2 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 3 : 2.000000 ps
Decay 4 : 2.000000 ps
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you have really shown is that the `decay` parameters do not change to 6 significant figures.   When  a fit is done, the parameter values are first changed by a very small amount (like 1.e-7) to generate the partial derivatives or Jacobian matrix. So printing out "only" six digits may not show the change made.

You don't give a complete script or the complete output.  Without knowing what `data` (and other variables) are, it is very hard to guess what might be going on.

It is certainly odd to do many fits (`len(wt)*len(wtau)`, whatever those are) **inside** a fit function itself, but maybe that is actually what you want to do -- I cannot tell what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: "data" size is (9,87,87); "len(wt)" equal to second dimensional size of data which size is 87, "len(wtau)" equal to "len(wt)". Consider data have 9 image with 87*87 pixel, they are decay with the time. I want to use 4 decay time with exponential function fit them along the time. I want to do the global fitting, A_i(w1,w2) and tau_i are parameters. There are so mangy parameters will need huge computer resources, so I try to divide the fitting to two parts.

Comment: And you are right, it change tiny. 
Decay 1 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 2 : 2.000000039736430 ps
Decay 3 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 4 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 1 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 2 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 3 : 2.000000039736430 ps
Decay 4 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 1 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 2 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 3 : 2.000000000000000 ps
Decay 4 : 2.000000039736430 ps
Decay 1 : 2.000000028648258 ps
Decay 2 : 2.000000026218526 ps
Decay 3 : 2.000000027587789 ps
Decay 4 : 2.000000026835256 ps

Comment: However, my strategy looks like doesn't works, since the fitting stopped after few iteration.

Comment: I would strongly suggest starting by breaking down the code to a much simpler problem.  Like, just do one of the inner fits with decay=2. Does that give a sensible result? Because it could be that the inner fit is just not sensitive to changes in `decay`.  I don't see how you are testing for that.